# $\Lambda$ a lattice in $\Bbb{C}^g$, $\Bbb{C}^{g'}$ is subvector space of $\Bbb{C}^g$. $\Lambda$ image in $\frac{\Bbb{C}^g}{\Bbb{C}^{g'}}$ a lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, lie-groups

$\Lambda$ is a lattice in $\Bbb{C}^g$ and $\Bbb{C}^{g'}$ is a subvector space of $\Bbb{C}^g$ where $\Bbb{C}$ is complex number.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Is $\Lambda$ image in $\frac{\Bbb{C}^g}{\Bbb{C}^{g'}}$ a lattice? I could not see discreteness of $\Lambda$'s image here. If not, what is the counter example?

Comment: Ok, I understand. Although you should not say that $\Bbb{C}$ is a complex number since it is rather the set of complex numbers

Answer (score 0):

No. Consider the case where $g=2$, $g'=1$ and consider the lattice $\Lambda$ which is generated as an abelian group by $(1,0),(i,0),(\sqrt2,1),(i\sqrt2,i)$ ($\Lambda$ is a lattice since the elements are a basis for $\Bbb{C}^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb{R}$). We need to be specific about which subspace of $\Bbb{C}^2$ we are referring to; consider the space $\{(0,x)|x\in \Bbb{C}\}\cong \Bbb{C}^1$. Then in the quotient, $\pi(\Lambda)$ will be generated by $\overline{(1,0)},\overline{(\sqrt2,0)},\overline{(i,0)},\overline{(i\sqrt2,0)}$ (where $\overline{(a,b)}$ denotes a coset in the quotient.). Then $\pi(\Lambda)$ will still be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^4$ as an abelian group. But to be a lattice in the quotient, it needs to be isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}^2$ since the quotient space has dimension $2$ over $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: I am pretty sure this answer is wrong as in $C=R^2$, the maximal rank is at most 2. There could not be a rank 4 free abelian group in $R^2$ or you will violate rank invariant theorem.

Comment: Are you referring to the theorem that the rank of a submodule over a PID is less than or equal to the rank of the original module?

Comment: In this case, to talk about the theorem, we need to think about $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ as $\Bbb{Z}$-modules since lattices are $\Bbb{Z}$-modules but not $\Bbb{R}$-modules. But $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$ have infinite rank as $\Bbb{Z}$-modules

Comment: What? $\Lambda$ is a lattice.(i.e. Discrete group.) The theorem says for discrete abelian subgroup/lattice in $R^n$, it can be as $Z-$module by at most $n$ elements. Ref. Pierre Samuel, Algebraic Number Theory, Thm 1 of chpt 4.

Comment: Ok, the problem then is that we did not project onto a lattice, but the theorem only applies to lattices/discrete abelian subgroups in $\Bbb{R}^n$. In the example, notice that the image of lambda is not a discrete subgroup